# Dependency between summation and subtraction of two standard normal distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

How to prove that $y_{1}= x_{1} + x_{2}$ and $y_{2} = x_{1} + x_{2}$ are either dependent or independent, where $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are two independent samples from standard normal distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are independent and here is the solution:
$p(y_1)$, $p(y_2)~N(0,2)$ and $p(y_1,y_2)~N(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\mu = [0;0]$, and $\Sigma = [2,0;0,2]$ [check this link to see how to compute the correlation between y1 and y2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties). As a result, joint distribution of $p(y_1,y_2)= \exp(-1/4(y_1^2+y_2^2))/4\pi$ and $p(y_1)*p(y_2)= \exp(-y_1^2/4)/2\sqrt(\pi)*\exp(-y_2^2/4)/2\sqrt(\pi)$. So they are independent :).